# Return the downside cell in an Excel Vlookup formula

Tags: microsoft-excel

In the following example I'm working with [Vlookup](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/vlookup.php).
The used formula is `=VLOOKUP(F15,C16:C19,1,TRUE)`

[image: LOOKUP]

As you can see I'm looking for the value 15000 in the array and this returns the match of 10000.

Now, I would like to know if there's a possibility to return the value of the down cell of the VLOOKUP, in this case would be 20000.

Comment: From the description for Vlookup and the last argument: `If you specify TRUE for the approximate_match parameter and no exact match is found, then the next smaller value is returned.`. I guess you need a completely new approach. Do you always want the next higher, always the next lower or always the nearest value to be returned?

Comment: Yes! In this case I need the higher approach :)

Comment: Are your values always ordered like shown? Can we use an offset which uses your normal Vlookup formula and then returnes the cell beneath? That would still search the smallest value. Therefore its crucial that your values are ordered

Comment: Yeah, They will be always ordered as shown, Because corresponds to a table data array of only numbers

Comment: Implement this with INDEX and MATCH instead of VLOOKUP.  You can then build the offset into your formula.

Comment: Sorry, Do you know how ? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
=if(index(C16:C19,match(F15,C16:C19,1))=F15,F15,index(C16:C19,match(F15,C16:C19,1)+1))
```